# Delete selected cells content in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a matrix. 
The main logic of the application is that any cell having a value of 0 will just display nothing (0 = no value in my referential).

Now what I want is that, when the user presses the Delete button, all the cells selected will be set to 0.
I can easily do that with one cell (because I keep track of the current row/column selected), but I can't get, let's say, a 2x2 square correctly.

The best way I figured out, using `Binding` magic, would be to get the row/column indexes of each cell selected, and then set the `Binding`'s source to 0. But still, I can't have all of the row numbers (basically because `grid.SelectedCells` is an `IEnumerable<DataGridCellInfo>`, and I can only get the column with this object, I have no way to get the current row.)

It works when I only select one cell(or one row), by using the following:

```
DataGridRow dataGridRow = (DataGridRow)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.CurrentItem);
```

How about multiple selection?

Any ideas here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get to the selected cells value:

```
DataGridCellInfo cell = dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0];
((TextBlock) cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item)).Text = "";
```

Counting that the cells are textblocks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It works fine. Would you know by any chance how to make it fire the OnCellEditEnding event automatically? Basically I update my binding upon CellEditEnding. I tried to surround your block by `BeginEdit()` & `EndEdit()` but it doesn't seem to do the trick :/

Comment: It doesn't work if selected cell isn't visible because of scroll.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (DataGridCellInfo cellInfo in grid.SelectedCells)
{
    DataGridColumn column = cellInfo.Column;
    string propertyName = ((Binding)column.ClipboardContentBinding).Path.Path;

    PropertyInfo pi = cellInfo.Item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (pi != null)
    {
        pi.SetValue(cellInfo.Item, null, null);
    }    
}

ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.Items);
cv.Refresh();
```